# How do I get a raw, compiled SQL query from a SQLAlchemy expression?

Tags: python, sql, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a SQLAlchemy query object and want to get the text of the compiled SQL statement, with all its parameters bound (e.g. no `%s` or other variables waiting to be bound by the statement compiler or MySQLdb dialect engine, etc).

Calling `str()` on the query reveals something like this:

```
SELECT id WHERE date_added <= %s AND date_added >= %s ORDER BY count DESC
```

I've tried looking in query._params but it's an empty dict.  I wrote my own compiler using [this example of the `sqlalchemy.ext.compiler.compiles` decorator](http://groups.google.com/group/sqlalchemy/browse_thread/thread/0c20a4f380e277af) but even the statement there still has `%s` where I want data.

I can't quite figure out when my parameters get mixed in to create the query; when examining the query object they're always an empty dictionary (though the query executes fine and the engine prints it out when you turn echo logging on).

I'm starting to get the message that SQLAlchemy doesn't want me to know the underlying query, as it breaks the general nature of the expression API's interface all the different DB-APIs.  I don't mind if the query gets executed before I found out what it was; I just want to know!

Answer (score 183, accepted):

[This blogpost by Nicolas Cadou](http://nicolascadou.com/blog/2014/01/printing-actual-sqlalchemy-queries/) provides an updated answer.

Quoting from the blog post, this is suggested and worked for me:

> ```
> from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql
> print str(q.statement.compile(dialect=postgresql.dialect()))
> ```

Where q is defined as:

> ```
> q = DBSession.query(model.Name).distinct(model.Name.value) \
>              .order_by(model.Name.value)
> ```

Or just any kind of `session.query()`.

Comment: Is there an easy way to get the values as a dictionary ?

Comment: @Damien given `c = q.statement.compile(...)`, you can just get `c.params`

Comment: The post is tagged with mysql, so the postgresql details in this answer aren't really relevant.

Comment: If I understand the OP correctly, he wants the final query. Printing with specifying a dialect (here postgres) still gives _me_ the placeholders instead of the literal values. @Matt's answer does the job. Getting the SQL with placeholders can be simplier achieved with the `as_scalar()`-method of `Query`.

Comment: @PatrickB. I agree.  Matt's answer should be considered the "correct" answer. I get the same result as this by just doing `str(q)`.

Comment: how do we do it for Core expression?

Comment: doing `q.statement.compile(compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True}).string` will return the string without calling str()

Comment: For snowflake, you can use `from snowflake.sqlalchemy import dialect as snowflake_dialect` and then `str(q.statement.compile(dialect=snowflake_dialect))`

Answer (score 199):

The [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/sqlexpressions.html) uses `literal_binds` to print a query `q` including parameters:

```
print(q.statement.compile(compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True}))
```

> the above approach has the caveats that it is only supported for basic types, such as ints and strings, and furthermore if a bindparam() without a pre-set value is used directly, it won’t be able to stringify that either.

The documentation also issues this warning:

> Never use this technique with string content received from untrusted
>   input, such as from web forms or other user-input applications.
>   SQLAlchemy’s facilities to coerce Python values into direct SQL string
>   values are not secure against untrusted input and do not validate the
>   type of data being passed. Always use bound parameters when
>   programmatically invoking non-DDL SQL statements against a relational
>   database.

Comment: Thank you! This was extremely helpful, allowed me to use pandas read_sql function painlessly!

Comment: @JustinPalmer does pandas not accept the query? Does it accept Core expression?

Comment: how can we do it for Core expression?

Comment: Unfortunately , the `literal_binds` approach is not able to bind python `bytes` data type with compiled SQL statement. In such case you may need to convert `bytes` to hex string in advance then figure out how the hex string can be passed with some built-in functions supported in your database

Answer (score 26):

This should work with Sqlalchemy >= 0.6

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import compiler

from psycopg2.extensions import adapt as sqlescape
# or use the appropiate escape function from your db driver

def compile_query(query):
    dialect = query.session.bind.dialect
    statement = query.statement
    comp = compiler.SQLCompiler(dialect, statement)
    comp.compile()
    enc = dialect.encoding
    params = {}
    for k,v in comp.params.iteritems():
        if isinstance(v, unicode):
            v = v.encode(enc)
        params[k] = sqlescape(v)
    return (comp.string.encode(enc) % params).decode(enc)
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  Sadly I'm using MySQL so my dialect is "positional" and needs to have a params list rather than a dictionary.  Currently trying to get your example to work with that..

Comment: Please don't use `adapt` in this manner.  At a minimum call prepare() on the return value from it each time, providing the connection as an argument, so it can do proper quoting.

Comment: @Alex: What would be the correct way to do proper quoting with psycopg? (besides calling prepare() on the return value, which you seem to imply is not optimal)

Comment: Sorry I think my phrasing was bad, as long as you do call obj.prepare(connection) you should be ok.  This is because "good" APIs that libpq provides for quoting require the connection (and it provides things like encoding for unicode strings).

Comment: Thanks. I've tried calling `prepare` on the return value but is seems that it doesn't have that method: `AttributeError: 'psycopg2._psycopg.AsIs' object has no attribute 'prepare'`. I'm using psycopg2 2.2.1 BTW

Comment: Ok, it seems `prepare()` isn't available in my old psycopg2 version, 2.3.1 seems to have it: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html?highlight=adapt#psycopg2.extensions.ISQLQuote.prepare

Comment: The port of this function to python 3 is http://stackoverflow.com/a/28227450/567606

Comment: @cce did you figure out the MySQL bit?

Comment: HI @TankorSmash I did and shared it in a different answer below http://stackoverflow.com/a/4618647/112380

Answer (score 24):

Thing is, sqlalchemy never mixes the data with your query. The query and the data are passed separately to your underlying database driver - the interpolation of data happens in your database.

Sqlalchemy passes the query as you've seen in `str(myquery)` to the database, and the values will go in a separate tuple.

You could use some approach where you interpolate the data with the query yourself (as albertov suggested below), but that's not the same thing that sqlalchemy is executing.

Comment: why isn't it the same thing?  I understand the DB-API is doing transactions, possibly re-ordering queries, etc, but could it be modifying my query more than this?

Comment: @cce: you're trying to find the final query. `SELECT id WHERE date_added <= %s AND date_added >= %s ORDER BY count DESC` **IS** the final query. Those `%s` are sent to the database by sqlalchemy -- sqlalchemy NEVER puts the actual data in place of the %s

Comment: @cce: Some dbapi modules don't do that either - that is often done by the database itself

Comment: aha I see what you're saying, thanks — digging further in `sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.mysqldb`, `do_executemany()` passes the statement & parameters separately to the MySQLdb cursor.  yay indirection!

Answer (score 18):

For the MySQLdb backend I modified albertov's awesome answer (thanks so much!) a bit.  I'm sure they could be merged to check if `comp.positional` was `True` but that's slightly beyond the scope of this question.

```
def compile_query(query):
    from sqlalchemy.sql import compiler
    from MySQLdb.converters import conversions, escape

    dialect = query.session.bind.dialect
    statement = query.statement
    comp = compiler.SQLCompiler(dialect, statement)
    comp.compile()
    enc = dialect.encoding
    params = []
    for k in comp.positiontup:
        v = comp.params[k]
        if isinstance(v, unicode):
            v = v.encode(enc)
        params.append( escape(v, conversions) )
    return (comp.string.encode(enc) % tuple(params)).decode(enc)
```

Comment: Awesome! I just needed the bound parameter list being sent to MySQL and modifying the above to just `return tuple(params)` worked like a charm! You saved me countless hours of having to go down an extremely painful road.

Answer (score 16):

First let me preface by saying that I assume you're doing this mainly for debugging purposes -- I wouldn't recommend trying to modify the statement outside of the SQLAlchemy fluent API.

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a simple way to show the compiled statement with the query parameters included. SQLAlchemy doesn't actually put the parameters into the statement -- they're [passed into the database engine as a dictionary](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/0901190bb440580f0664fe3f6310173762b908e0/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/oursql.py#L90). This lets the database-specific library handle things like escaping special characters to avoid SQL injection.

But you can do this in a two-step process reasonably easily. To get the statement, you can do as you've already shown, and just print the query:

```
>>> print(query)
SELECT field_1, field_2 FROM table WHERE id=%s;
```

You can get one step closer with query.statement, to see the parameter names. Note `:id_1` below vs `%s` above -- not really a problem in this very simple example, but could be key in a more complicated statement.

```
>>> print(query.statement)
>>> print(query.statement.compile()) # seems to be equivalent, you can also
                                     # pass in a dialect if you want
SELECT field_1, field_2 FROM table WHERE id=:id_1;
```

Then, you can get the actual values of the parameters by getting the `params` property of the compiled statement:

```
>>> print(query.statement.compile().params)
{u'id_1': 1}
```

This worked for a MySQL backend at least; I would expect it's also general enough for PostgreSQL without needing to use `psycopg2`.

Comment: From within the PyCharm debugger, the following worked for me... _qry.compile().params_

Comment: Interesting, could be SQLAlchemy has changed a bit since I wrote this answer.

Answer (score 14):

For postgresql backend using psycopg2, you can listen for the `do_execute` event, then use the cursor, statement and type coerced parameters along with `Cursor.mogrify()` to inline the parameters. You can return True to prevent actual execution of the query.

```
import sqlalchemy

class QueryDebugger(object):
    def __init__(self, engine, query):
        with engine.connect() as connection:
            try:
                sqlalchemy.event.listen(engine, "do_execute", self.receive_do_execute)
                connection.execute(query)
            finally:
                sqlalchemy.event.remove(engine, "do_execute", self.receive_do_execute)

    def receive_do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context):
        self.statement = statement
        self.parameters = parameters
        self.query = cursor.mogrify(statement, parameters)
        # Don't actually execute
        return True
```

Sample usage:

```
>>> engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("postgresql://postgres@localhost/test")
>>> metadata = sqlalchemy.MetaData()
>>> users = sqlalchemy.Table('users', metadata, sqlalchemy.Column("_id", sqlalchemy.String, primary_key=True), sqlalchemy.Column("document", sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSONB))
>>> s = sqlalchemy.select([users.c.document.label("foobar")]).where(users.c.document.contains({"profile": {"iid": "something"}}))
>>> q = QueryDebugger(engine, s)
>>> q.query
'SELECT users.document AS foobar \nFROM users \nWHERE users.document @> \'{"profile": {"iid": "something"}}\''
>>> q.statement
'SELECT users.document AS foobar \nFROM users \nWHERE users.document @> %(document_1)s'
>>> q.parameters
{'document_1': '{"profile": {"iid": "something"}}'}
```

Comment: This is the best answer for Postgres! Unlike the method that uses `literal_binds`, this works with any parameter types.

Answer (score 9):

The following solution uses the SQLAlchemy Expression Language and works with SQLAlchemy 1.1. This solution does not mix the parameters with the query (as requested by the original author), but provides a way of using SQLAlchemy models to generate SQL query strings and parameter dictionaries for different SQL dialects. The example is based on the tutorial http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/tutorial.html

Given the class,

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()
class foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(80), unique=True)
    value = Column(Integer())
```

we can produce a query statement using the **select** function.

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import select    
statement = select([foo.name, foo.value]).where(foo.value > 0)
```

Next, we can compile the statement into a query object.

```
query = statement.compile()
```

By default, the statement is compiled using a basic 'named' implementation that is compatible with SQL databases such as SQLite and Oracle. If you need to specify a dialect such as PostgreSQL, you can do

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql
query = statement.compile(dialect=postgresql.dialect())
```

Or if you want to explicitly specify the dialect as SQLite, you can change the paramstyle from 'qmark' to 'named'.

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects import sqlite
query = statement.compile(dialect=sqlite.dialect(paramstyle="named"))
```

From the query object, we can extract the query string and query parameters

```
query_str = str(query)
query_params = query.params
```

and finally execute the query.

```
conn.execute( query_str, query_params )
```

Comment: How is this answer better/different than AndyBarr's one posted 2 years earlier?

Comment: AndyBarr's answer includes an example of generating a query statement with a DBSession whereas this answer includes an example​ using the declarative API and select method. With respect to compiling the query statement with a certain dialect, the answers are the same. I use SQLAlchemy to generate raw queries and then execute them with Twister's adbapi. For this use case, knowing how to compile the query without a session and to extract the query string and parameters is useful.

Comment: @eric and how come you are not using just raw SQL?

Answer (score 4):

UPDATE: Came up with yet another case where the previous solution here wasn't properly producing the correct SQL statement. After a bit of diving around in SQLAlchemy, it becomes apparent that you not only need to compile for a particular dialect, you also need to take the compiled query and initialize it for the correct DBAPI connection context. Otherwise, things like type bind processors don't get executed and values like JSON.NULL don't get properly translated.

Note, this makes this solution very particular to Flask + Flask-SQLAlchemy + psycopg2 + PostgreSQL. You may need to translate this solution to your environment by changing the dialect and how you reference your connection. However, I'm pretty confident this produces the exact SQL for all data types.

The result below is a simple method to drop in and occasionally but reliably grab the exact, compiled SQL that would be sent to my PostgreSQL backend by just interrogating the query itself:

```
import sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.psycopg2

from flask import current_app

def query_to_string(query):
    dialect = sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.psycopg2.dialect()
    compiled_query = query.statement.compile(dialect=dialect)
    sqlalchemy_connection = current_app.db.session.connection()
    context = dialect.execution_ctx_cls._init_compiled(
        dialect,
        sqlalchemy_connection,
        sqlalchemy_connection.connection,
        compiled_query,
        None
    )
    mogrified_query = sqlalchemy_connection.connection.cursor().mogrify(
        context.statement,
        context.parameters[0]
    )
    return mogrified_query.decode()

query = [ .... some ORM query .... ]

print(f"compiled SQL = {query_to_string(query)}")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use events from [ConnectionEvents](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/events.html?highlight=after_cursor#sql-execution-and-connection-events) family: [`after_cursor_execute`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/events.html?highlight=after_cursor#sqlalchemy.events.ConnectionEvents.after_cursor_execute) or [`before_cursor_execute`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/events.html?highlight=after_cursor#sqlalchemy.events.ConnectionEvents.before_cursor_execute).

In sqlalchemy [UsageRecipes](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/wiki/UsageRecipes/) by @zzzeek you can find this example:

```
Profiling

...
@event.listens_for(Engine, "before_cursor_execute")
def before_cursor_execute(conn, cursor, statement,
                        parameters, context, executemany):
    conn.info.setdefault('query_start_time', []).append(time.time())
    logger.debug("Start Query: %s" % statement % parameters)
...
```

Here you can get access to your *statement*

Answer (score 2):

I've created this little function that I import when I want to print the full query, considering I'm in the middle of a test when the dialect is already bound:

```
import re

def print_query(query):
    regex = re.compile(":(?P<name>\w+)")
    params = query.statement.compile().params
    sql = regex.sub("'{\g<name>}'", str(query.statement)).format(**params)
    print(f"\nPrinting SQLAlchemy query:\n\n")
    print(sql)
    return sql
```

Answer (score 0):

I think .statement would possibly do the trick:
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html?highlight=query

```
>>> local_session.query(sqlalchemy_declarative.SomeTable.text).statement
<sqlalchemy.sql.annotation.AnnotatedSelect at 0x6c75a20; AnnotatedSelectobject>
>>> x=local_session.query(sqlalchemy_declarative.SomeTable.text).statement
>>> print(x)
SELECT sometable.text 
FROM sometable
```

Comment: Statement doesn't show you what the parameters are, if you have some kinds of filters set up.

Answer (score 0):

If with SQLAlchemy you are using PyMySQL, you can do one trick.

I was in a hurry and lost a lot of time, so I changed the driver for print the current statement with parameters.

SQLAlchemy intentionally does not support full stringification of literal values.

But PyMySQL has 'mogrify' method which does it, but, SQLALchemy has no HOOK for call it when using ORM insert/update (when it controls the cursor) like db.add or commit/flush (for update).

So, Just go where the driver is using (to know where use):
pip show pycharm

In the folder, find and edit the file cursors.py.

In the method:

```
def execute(self, query, args=None):
```

Under the line:

```
query = self.mogrify(query, args)
```

Just Add:

```
print(query)
```

Will work like a charm, debug, resolve the issue and remove the print.

Comment: There is a hook - use the `before_cursor_execute` listener as shown in [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31833508/5320906).

Comment: This HOOK not work for statements generate by the ORM from the model like db.add.Only for statements using cursor, so useless for my case.