# How can I do multiple "order_by" in Flask-SQLAlchemy?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Let's say I have a `User` model with fields `popularity` and `date_created`. I want to do the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY popularity DESC, date_created DESC LIMIT 10
```

In SQLAlchemy, for a single one this works:

```
User.query.order_by(User.popularity.desc()).limit(10).all()
```

Should I just add another `order_by()`? Or put both `popularity` and `date_created` in my current `order_by()`?

I want `popularity` to have priority on `date_created` for ordering.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

This should work

```
User.query.order_by(User.popularity.desc(), User.date_created.desc()).limit(10).all()
```

Comment: Well the fact is that I tried
    `User.query.order_by(User.popularity.desc(),User.date_created.desc()).limit(10).all()`

`User.query.order_by(User.popularity.desc()).order_by(User.date_created.desc()).limit(10).all()`

`User.query.order_by(User.date_created.desc()).limit(10).all()`

and they give me different results...

So it seems that giving a second order_by neither overrides the first one nor adds the order condition to the first one?

Comment: (and none of these queries fails, they all give me results, I just don't know which one of the first two is the one I want)

Comment: Ok, actually both give me the same answer, and I found out the underlying SQL query (thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617291/how-do-i-get-a-raw-compiled-sql-query-from-a-sqlalchemy-expression ) and they are indeed the same, and the right one. Sorry, and thank you so much for your answer !

Comment: For anyone wondering if there is a difference between `order_by(o1).order_by(o2)` and `order_by(o1, o2)`, there is not. In the first case I thought is it being overwritten by the second `order_by`, but no. It's working just as expected.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use `sqlalchemy.sql.text` like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import text

User.query.order_by(text("popularity desc, date_created desc")).limit(10).all()
```

Comment: From my testing, it seems that you need to sanitize what gets into `text()` if you get it from untrusted source. For example, SQLAlchemy happily allowed: `.order_by(text('id desc; DROP TABLE important_table;'))` to go into generated SQL, although some other error prevented this to be executed in my case.

Answer (score 5):

What you also could do:

```
from sqlalchemy import and_, or_
User.query.order_by(and_(User.popularity.desc(), User.date_created.desc())).all()
```

Note: `and_` and `or_` are coming from the sqlalchemy library and not from flask_sqlalchemy library.
sqlalchemy is a dependency for flask_sqlalchemy, so you should be good.

LTS: You can mix sqlalchemy lib with flask_alchemy lib

Answer (score 1):

I have another example:

```
user = User.query.order_by(User.id.desc()).limit(10).all()

s.t
```

User is my class db.Modle