# how to get the list of all the failed tasks from different dags

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

We have below command, we can clear the failed tasks and rerun them in a single attempt

```
airflow clear [-s START_DATE] [-e END_DATE] --only_failed dag_id
```

Is there any way we can get the information of all the failed tasks from all the dags and export it into file (excel or text)

Answer (score 6):

Here's an *untested* code snippet that should help you

- Obtain list of failed `TaskInstance`s (you can modify this to add filters like `dag_id` and `start_date`)

  ```
   from typing import List, Optional
   from airflow.models.taskinstance import TaskInstance
   from airflow.utils import State
   from airflow.settings import Session
   from airflow.utils.db import provide_session

   @provide_session
   def get_failed_task_instances(session: Optional[Session] = None) -> List[TaskInstance]:
       """
       Returns list of failed TaskInstance(s)
        - for all DAGs since inception of time
        - sorted by (1) dag_id ASC (2) start_date DESC
       :param session: Optional[Session]
       :return: List[TaskInstance]
       """
       failed_task_instances: List[TaskInstance] = session.query(TaskInstance). \
           filter(TaskInstance.state == State.FAILED). \
           order_by(TaskInstance.dag_id.asc(), TaskInstance.start_date.desc()). \
           all()
       return failed_task_instances
  ```
- (Utility function to) Extract relevant bits from `TaskInstance` like `dag_id`, `start_date` & `task_id` (change it as per your need)

  ```
   def ti_to_string(ti: TaskInstance) -> List[str]:
       """
       Converts a TaskInstance in List[str] by extracting relevant bits of info from it
       :param ti: TaskInstance
       :return: List[str]
       """
       return [ti.dag_id, ti.start_date, ti.task_id]
  ```
- Putting it all together: writing data to output CSV file

  ```
   import csv
   def write_failed_task_instances_to_csv(output_file_path: str) -> None:
       """
       Writes list of failed tasks in the provided output CSV filepath
       :param output_file_path:
       :return: None
       """
       # prepare list of failed TaskInstance(s)
       failed_task_instances: List[TaskInstance] = get_failed_task_instances()
       # extract relevant bits of info from TaskInstance(s) list (to serialize them)
       failed_task_instances_data: List[List[str]] = list(map(ti_to_string, failed_task_instances))
       # write data of failed TaskInstance(s) to output CSV filepath
       with open(output_file_path, "w", newline="") as f:
           writer = csv.writer(f)
           writer.writerows(failed_task_instances_data)
  ```

---

References

- [`views.py`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/caa60b1141ac02cdde1c33464be9adca114c2ed5/airflow/www/views.py#L684): *this file is a goto place to uncover that `SQLAlchemy` magic of Airflow*
- [SQLAlchemy multiple order_bys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15792183/3679900)
- [Writing a Python list of list to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14037564/3679900)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. Is there a possibility we can get last executed time for a particular dag run ?

Comment: if i have a dag like " dag_employee_info "  , can i get latest completed run timestamp for this dag . any suggestion pls ?

Comment: **@Ravi** last execution time of DAG **[1]** you can build it yourself by exploiting `SQLAlchemy` [`DagRun` model](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/21021228759da8d3e98ca3f6d0922a6e9a0b5e68/airflow/models/dagrun.py#L44) as in above answer. **[2]** you can take first line from o/p of [`list_dag_runs`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/cli-ref#list_dag_runs) CLI command **[3]** A quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=airflow+get+last+dag+run) yields results like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57607042/3679900) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51923684/3679900)