# flake8 complains on boolean comparison "==" in filter clause

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flake8

I have a boolean field in the mysql db table.

```
# table model
class TestCase(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test_cases'
    ...
    obsoleted = Column('obsoleted',  Boolean)
```

To get the count of all the non-obsoleted test cases, that can be done simply like this:

```
caseNum = session.query(TestCase).filter(TestCase.obsoleted == False).count()
print(caseNum)
```

That works fine, but the flake8 report the following warning:

> E712: Comparison to False should be "if cond is False:" or "if not
>   cond:"

Okay, I think that make sense. So change my code to this:

```
caseNum = session.query(TestCase).filter(TestCase.obsoleted is False).count()
```

or

```
caseNum = session.query(TestCase).filter(not TestCase.obsoleted).count()
```

But neither of them can work.  The result is always 0.
I think the filter clause doesn't support the operator "is" or "is not". Will someone can tell me how to handle this situation. I don't want to disable the flake.

Comment: [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) specifically advises *against* "if cond is False". I'm surprised that the [pep8 tool](http://pep8.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro.html) does the opposite.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

That's because SQLAlchemy filters are one of the few places where `== False` actually makes sense. **Everywhere else** you should *not* use it.

Add a `# noqa` comment to the line and be done with it.

Or you can use [`sqlalchemy.sql.expression.false`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.false):

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import false

TestCase.obsoleted == false()
```

where `false()` returns the right value for your session SQL dialect. There is a matching [`sqlalchemy.expression.true`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=true#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.true).

Answer (score 122):

SQL Alchemy also has `is_` and `isnot` functions you can use. An example would be

```
Model.filter(Model.deleted.is_(False))
```

[More on those here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.is_)

Comment: In Python `is` and `==` are different but I'm pretty sure the SQL being generated here will be the same.

Comment: `is` and `==` are different in SQLAlchemy because you cannot override the identity operator (`is`) in python. An expression like `Model.column is False` is always evaluated as `False` because the comparison always happens immediately in python and not the database. The result of comparing the identity of a column object and a boolean is always `False`. This inserts statements like `WHERE FALSE` or `AND FALSE` into your query, which in most cases will cause it to return 0 rows no matter what.

Comment: Not working with Oracle

Answer (score 25):

I have a look what exact query is generated for using `SQLAlchemy` when `==` and [`is_`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.is_) when the [database dialect is `Postgresql`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25563491/953553) for boolean field:

- for `==` we get:

  1. `field == False` is converted to `field = false`
  2. `field == True` is converted to `field = true`
  3. `field == None` is converted to `field IS NULL`
- for `is_()` we get:

  1. `field.is_(False)` is converted to `field IS false`
  2. `field.is_(True)` is converted to `field IS true`
  3. `field.is_(None)` is converted to `field IS NULL`

**NOTE:** `is_(not None)` will be evaluated to `is_(bool(not None)` what gives `is_(True)` giving `field = true` so you rather go for `isnot(None)` producing  `field IS NOT NULL`

Comment: And also note that when you uses `is` rather than `=` in PostgreSQL, you will never get NULL as an answer, even if an operand is NULL. `=` will return NULL if either operand is NULL.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use `.filter_by(field=True)` / `.filter_by(field=False)` ?

Comment: One thing to watch for if you've joined table filter_by can be ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

```py
caseNum = session.query(TestCase).filter(~TestCase.obsoleted).count()
print(caseNum)
```

works.try it in your sqlalchemy versions

Answer (score 1):

@Jruv Use `# noqa` in front of statement, it'll ignore the warning.

Comment: `# noqa` will disable flake8 / pep / other-linters for the **entire** string, so other linting-warnings will be ignored too. Other answers offer better solutions, for example, `.is_`-method.