# SqlAlchemy : I want to filter query on 2 foreign keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have 2 tables (say `Student` and `College`) and a third table, which has `student_id` and `college_id` foreign keys.

I don't want to hard delete `Student` and `College` rows, so I have included a `deleted(Boolean)` column in both tables.

I want to add a student to a college (by adding `student_id` and and `college_id` to the third table). I first want to check if that student already exists in the college and also want to filter the deleted records for student and college.

for the first part I have written:

```
db.session.query(StudentCollegeMappingModel).filter(
    StudentCollegeMappingModel.student_id==student_id,
    StudentCollegeMappingModel.college_id==college_id
).first()
```

but I also want to check if

```
Student.deleted==False and College.deleted==False
```

How should I do it?

Comment: Have you configured relationships between the tables? Can you share a little bit of your model definitions?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I see a `session.query` question not a `model` one. Whatsoever

Comment: @KostasCharitidis: that has nothing to do with the question, really. `StudentCollegeMappingModel.query` or `db.session.query(StudentCollegeMappingModel)` are just two ways of creating the initial query object, when using Flask-SQLAlchemy. What has that got to do with your 'use multiple filters' comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to join the `Student` and `College` tables to your query so you can filter on the `deleted` columns:

```
query = (
    StudentCollegeMappingModel.query
    .join(Student, Student.id == StudentCollegeMappingModel.student_id)
    .join(College, College.id == StudentCollegeMappingModel.college_id)
    .filter(
        StudentCollegeMappingModel.student_id == student_id,
        StudentCollegeMappingModel.college_id == college_id,
        Student.deleted.is_(False),
        College.deleted.is_(False),
    )
)
```

I used `StudentCollegeMappingModel.query` rather than `db.session.query(StudentCollegeMappingModel)`; they produce the same initial `Query` instance, but Flask-SQLAlchemy tries to make it easier for you by giving you the `.query` property.

You probably can omit the `Student.id == StudentCollegeMappingModel.student_id` and `College.id == StudentCollegeMappingModel.college_id` `ON` clauses here, provided you configured `student_id` and `college_id` as `ForeignKey()` columns and there are no other relationships between the tables that might confuse SQLAlchemy:

```
query = (
    StudentCollegeMappingModel.query.join(Student).join(College)
    .filter(
        StudentCollegeMappingModel.student_id == student_id,
        StudentCollegeMappingModel.college_id == college_id,
        Student.deleted.is_(False),
        College.deleted.is_(False),
    )
)
```

You can also use [`from sqlalchemy.sql.expression.false` with `==`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998010/flake8-complains-on-boolean-comparison-in-filter-clause):

```
query = (
    StudentCollegeMappingModel.query.join(Student).join(College)
    .filter(
        StudentCollegeMappingModel.student_id == student_id,
        StudentCollegeMappingModel.college_id == college_id,
        Student == false(),
        College == false(),
    )
)
```

Note that you could use the above query as an `NOT EXISTS` filter when inserting the new record; that would help prevent race conditions (where multiple pieces of code try to make the same change, or where some are setting `deleted` columns after you tested this but before you insert.

Comment: I've seen aliasing of `True` and `False` to get around using `==` with linters before but wasn't aware of the expression functions. I like that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use joins

```
db.session.query(StudentCollegeMappingModel, Student, College)
    .join(StudentCollegeMappingModel)
    .join(Student)
    .join(College)
    .filter(StudentCollegeMappingModel.student_id == Student.id, StudentCollegeMappingModel.college_id==college_id,Student.deleted==False, College.deleted==False)
    ).all()
```