# I'm getting no data from sqlalchemy query?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

This is my model:

```
class Huse(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    bord = db.Column(db.Text)
    voksne = db.Column(db.Integer)
    born = db.Column(db.Integer)
    auto = db.Column(db.Boolean)
```

This query gives me the below data:

```
result = Huse.query.all()
```

(Formatting left out)

```
{"199": {"bord": "1", "voksne": 2, "born": 2, "auto": false}, "201": {"bord": "1", "voksne": 2, "born": 2, "auto": true}, "211": {"bord": "1", "voksne": 2, "born": 2, "auto": false}, "217": {"bord": "1", "voksne": 2, "born": 2, "auto": true}}
```

But if I do this query:

```
    result = Huse.query.filter(Huse.auto is True)
```

I get nothing. 
Can annyone please explain to me what's wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [flake8 complains on boolean comparison "==" in filter clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998010/flake8-complains-on-boolean-comparison-in-filter-clause)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sqlalchemy doesn't directly support python's "is" syntax.  Try replacing `is` with `==`.