# sqlalchemy can't get data with boolean field in filter option (specified with is)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
Channel.query.filter(Channel.is_default == True).all()
```

When I use above expression it works,but an pep8 advice is occuered.So I use below expression instead.

```
Channel.query.filter(Channel.is_default is True).all()
```

But when I run the code, no data returned.And there is no error or warning.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [flake8 complains on boolean comparison "==" in filter clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998010/flake8-complains-on-boolean-comparison-in-filter-clause)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>~When you're dealing with a property or method that returns boolean values, there is absolutely no need to compare it with `True` or `False`. It's a bad practice, even.</strike>

So, to solve both your PEP8 problem, and your filtering one, just omit the comparison, since `Channel.is_default` will already yield `True` or `False` individually:

```py
Channel.query.filter(Channel.is_default).all()
```

And if that filter doesn't give you any results, it's because not `all` within your `Channel` have `is_default` set to `True`. This filter is as straightforward as they come.

Edit: my answer was misinformed, the `filter` function in sqlalchemy is a very particular case of conditionality in Python. See [this question and its most prominent answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998010/flake8-complains-on-boolean-comparison-in-filter-clause), which also answer OP's question as of now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Now I know how to solve PEP8.But I have no idea about what do you mean in the final paragraph.In the database,is_default field is a bollean field.(0 or  1)And there are some records set is_default to 1.So i can get data with the expression:
Channel.query.filter(Channel.is_default == True).all().True can be replace with 1.But replace '==' with is will get no data.That is the most important part!

Comment: By the way, I just tried your expression and it did work.Now I wonder how to judge 'Channel.is_default' to be False.Thanks.

Comment: The fact that the field is binary doesn't matter, since Python considers 0 to be False and 1 to be True in conditional structures (check the [truthy-falsy in Python](https://freecodecamp.org/news/truthy-and-falsy-values-in-python)). But I've just noticed your question is duplicated, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998010/flake8-complains-on-boolean-comparison-in-filter-clause). I won't update my answer since it was misinformed to begin with, but you can do as the first or second answers suggest