# Is there a way to make SQLAlchemy pre-compile a query?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

When profiling an application, I've found out that SQLAlchemy compiling SQL is one of tasks that takes most of CPU time of the app. I've already made bound parameters explicit, but it appears that SQLAlchemy only compiles the query when it's time to execute it.

Is there a way to make it pre-compile the query so that only minimal work is required to replace the bound parameters before executing it?

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617291/how-do-i-get-a-raw-compiled-sql-query-from-a-sqlalchemy-expression

Comment: Simeon: PostgreSQL; Ian: thanks

Comment: Are you using the ORM? If so, and if the problem is that you have a lot of repeated queries, SQLAlchemy 1.0 has a new feature called [Baked Queries](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/baked.html) that may be of use / interest here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way... kind of. I was already defining the query at module parsing time:

```
class MyClass(object):
    # This works (slow)
    query = select(...).where(...).order_by('distance').limit(1)
    ...

    @classmethod
    def issue_query(cls, **params):
        cls.engine.execute(cls.query, params)
```

But SQLAlchemy kept only compiling MyClass.query only when MyClass.issue_query was called (every time it was called). I've noticed that defining the query as a `text()` made it pretty fast (120us vs 600us)... but `str(query)` compiles the query into pretty much a `text()` argument, so I've tried defining it as:

```
class MyClass(object):
    # This doesn't work
    query = text(str(select(...).where(...).order_by('distance').limit(1)))
    ...

    @classmethod
    def issue_query(cls, **params):
        cls.engine.execute(cls.query, params)
```

But SQLAlchemy tries to make sense of the `'distance'` inside `order_by()` and converts the `1` inside `limit()` to a bound parameter (that is, removes the value from the query). This can be solved with a little hack:

```
class MyClass(object):
    # This works (fast)
    query = text(str(select(...).where(...).order_by(text('distance')).limit(text('1'))))
    ...

    @classmethod
    def issue_query(cls, **params):
        cls.engine.execute(cls.query, params)
```

Comment: Just found out that you can't use any bound parameters this way. Not even using bindparam().