# How do I generate constant WHERE condition in SQL Alchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to generate a certain SQL statement with SQLAlchemy where there is an existing schema and data inside the database. I approach it like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Session = sessionmaker()
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///example.db')
Session.configure(bind=engine)
session = Session()
base = declarative_base()
base.metadata.reflect(engine)

table = Table('dane', base.metadata, autoload=True)
q = session.query(table).filter(table.c.title == 'A')
print(q)
```

When I examine the rendered (generated) query from the above code it generates this:

```
SELECT dane.title AS dane_title, dane.body AS dane_body 
FROM dane 
WHERE dane.title = ?
```

I do not need, however, a dynamic statement, I need the `?` in the query to be **exactly** `A` as would the `.filter` call suggest. How can I achieve a constant `WHERE` expression with SQLAlchemy?

## UPDATE

SA actually does generate constant WHERE conditions. To see them you need to pass special kwargs to compile():

`.compile(compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True})`

as in @metatoaster's answer below.

Comment: Rendering the query that way will always show a bind, but the query itself definitely has exactly `A`.  What exactly do you mean?  If you want a static statement, why not just write it out as is?

Comment: This query is an example, I have a more complex query built with SQLAlchemy and there are `bindparam`s  there. What I cannot seem to achieve is the mix of the two - exact `WHERE` and a data-bound `WHERE`.

Comment: Try `print(q.statement.compile(compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True}))`; I am operating on that you only wanted to see the query, as you have not described _why_ you need this and _what_ you are using this for.

Comment: If that does exactly what you wanted, it is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617291/how-do-i-get-a-raw-compiled-sql-query-from-a-sqlalchemy-expression; otherwise edit your question to be more specific by including what exactly you want to achieve and/or why you need this.

Comment: What I needed is exactly what I've written - a `WHERE` condition that matches a constant string value. The answer is, I suppose, that SA does what it's told, it just wasn't clear (to a SA newbie) how the actual query looked like. I edited the question to state 'constant' instead of 'static'. Thank you very much for the quick clarification! This question is not a duplicate however, as seeing the resultant query was not the goal.

Comment: It is still not clear as to **why** you are doing this, but more in-depth explanation given anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query at generation is already static but does not look bounded is because [`sqlalchemy` always parameterize all query values](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#insert-expressions) no matter where they come from [to prevent SQL injection attacks by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements).  This however does not mean the query is not static.  For a complete example, create a table fully in memory (using sqlalchemy) plus other setup.

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import MetaData, create_engine, Table, Column, String
>>> metadata = MetaData()
>>> metadata.bind = create_engine('sqlite:///')
>>> table = Table('table', metadata,
...     Column('name', String(), nullable=False),
... )
>>> metadata.create_all()
>>> table.insert().values(name='value').execute()
```

Get a generic query working to see that we got some data.

```
>>> from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
>>> Session = sessionmaker()
>>> Session.configure(bind=metadata.bind)
>>> session = Session()
>>> session.query(table).all()
[('value',)]
```

Now, instead of supplying a string, we supply a variable to the query.

```
>>> value = 'value'
>>> q = session.query(table).filter(table.c.name == value)
```

Change the value, execute the query

```
>>> value = 'somethingelse'
>>> q.all()
[('value',)]
```

It is as "static" as one might expect.  Also note that in the documentation (the tutorial) linked earlier, the data *is* stored in the construct, just not rendered.