# pymongo to extract query in pyython to mongod's javascript query syntax

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongo-shell

### In brief

We have query written in Python via pymongo package as below sample and we want to run the same query via mongo cli in console. How can we do that ie. to get the javascript syntax of that query?

Similar need for postgres can be archieved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4617291/248616)

### In full

Let's take below sample code

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client  = MongoClient('mongodb://YOUR_HOST:27017/', connect=False)
mongodb = client['YOUR_DB']
docs = mongodb['YOUR_COLLECTION'].aggregate([
    {'$match':{
        'someField': 'someFilter',
    }},
], allowDiskUse=True)
```

I want to run that query, ie. the javascript syntax version, via mongo cli in console e.g. on another server that has full documents/rows.

My [google search](https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=pymongo%20extract%20mongod%20javascript%20query%20syntax&oq=pymongo%20extract%20mongod%20javascript%20query%20syntax&aqs=chrome..69i57.17770j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and [search on our site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pymongo%20extract%20mongod%20javascript%20query%20syntax#) result little helpful so I asked here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [Javascript Syntax of the Pymongo aggregation query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) for the MongoDB shell.

```
db.YOUR_COLLECTION.aggregate(
  [{$match: {someField: someFilter}}], 
  {allowDiskUse: true}
)
```

Comment: Any way to get that automatically?

Comment: @NamGVU None that I know of.  If you'll like to use the Javascript query for maintenance reasons e.g. your team mostly been familiar with Javascript queries. You can use `Code` objects for your queries.

Comment: It's not the matter of javascript-friendly in the team. We both work with python and javascript for mongo. But on production server, we can hardly run python mongo query ie. we use mongo cli.

Comment: About Code object, may you clarify that? Thank you.