# sqlalchemy - view what is about to be executed

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sql-insert

Is there a way to view the INSERT command the sqlalchemy is about to execute?

My scenario is as follow:

1. adding an object to the session - `session.add(my_obj)`
2. executing the insert by calling - `session.flush()`

I know how to view the content of a SELECT request:

```
print(q.statement.compile(compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True}))
```

thanks to: [How do I get a raw, compiled SQL query from a SQLAlchemy expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617291/how-do-i-get-a-raw-compiled-sql-query-from-a-sqlalchemy-expression)

Comment: hello, isn't it so to put echo=True in the creation of the engine?
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgres://foo/bar', echo=True)

Comment: thank you @CaioFilus, I was hoping for something more detailed. I'm getting a truncated message: `[SQL: INSERT INTO my_table (id, name, ...) VALUES (%(id)s, %(name)s, ...)]
[parameters: [{'id': 123, 'name': 'test' ... (276 characters truncated) ... ]]`