# any way to import csv file to firebird from sql cmd?

Tags: sql, firebird

I need to import few columns from csv file into firebird temp table
but not using any tool only from sql editor aka openrowset in SQL server.
is it supported?
thanks

Comment: You could write a script that turns CSV into SQL `insert` statements and execute that. Anyway **never trust the input, check and sanitize**.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8213/62576

Comment: What do you mean with "only from SQL editor"? Which SQL tool are you using?

Comment: I use EBEasy+ and SQL Manager lite for firebird

Comment: hard to believe firbird doesn't hsave load statement or something like that...

Comment: @ZuluZ Firebird has external tables, but the dataformat is a binary format

Answer (score 1):

firebird doesn't have a load statement, but several tools have an import module. Easest is to edit the file into a set of insert statements

Answer (score 1):

You can have look at [Data Transformer](https://geosystemsdev.com/products/data-transformer/) (disclaimer - I'm its developer). It can convert between CSV (an other formats) to SQL. The generated SQL contains "insert" statements for each line and a "create table" statement.

It works offline - the data never leaves your computer.

You can get it from the [Mac App Store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/data-transformer/id1490843070) or the [Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/p/data-transformer/9p2xp6nt2pv2).